# TWiki mailnotify mails not being sent

Tags: twiki

I've installed Twiki and when I run  the following command:

```
perl -I bin tools/mailnotify SomeWeb
```

I get the message stating that the notifications have been sent:

```
Processing SomeWeb
   * myname@mydomain.com : *
      Last notification was at ...
      Change to SomeTopic at ... New revision is NN

Notified myname@mydomin.com of changes in SomeWeb
      1 change notifications from SomeWeb
```

However, I'm not getting any e-mail with the notification.

It's seem to be some configuration problem, but I can't figure out what... I haven't found where to configure anything (the smpt server to use, the account on the smtp server to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you send emails using mailx or some other cli client?  I think twiki is relying on something like sendmail already being installed to do the sending.  Here's a line out of their documentation, not sure how recent.

> SMTPMAILHOST is typically set on Windows or other non-Unix/Linux systems, where sendmail or similar is not available. When this is set and the Perl module Net::SMTP is installed, TWiki will connect to this SMTP server (e.g. mail.yourdomain.com) to send email for user registration and WebChangesAlerts. If you do have a sendmail-type program, leave SMTPMAILHOST unset so that the external sendmail program is used instead (defined by $mailProgram in TWiki.cfg).